# Ionic 2 - multiple popovers on Page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Today I'm working with Ionic 2 Pages using Angular 2 Stack.
I have navbar with few  (icons) and two of them should open a Popover.

My question is: how to handle multiple Popovers on one page? How to prevent presenting two popovers at the same time (**always should be just one visible**)?

Default code from doc is as follows:

```
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyPopOverPage } from './my-pop-over';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {
  }

  presentPopover() {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(MyPopOverPage);
    popover.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: You state you want multiple popovers but your example only shows the creation on one popover. I have not tested this but maybe pass the popover name into the function `(click)="presentPopover(myPopover)"` and then loop through all the popovers and `.dismiss()` everything that is !not `myPopover`

Answer (score 0):

The line of code:

`let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(MyPopOverPage);`

Is creating a handle to an instance of a popover. To create another popover just create another handle with a different name.

Example:

`let popover2 = this.popoverCtrl.create(MyPopOverPage);`

Now you can control either popover by referencing either `popover` or `popover2`. Map these handles to some form of collection along with Boolean isActive flags and then you can compare them.